# asp.net ajax update panel confusion

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Well, i have this in my master page

```
<cc1:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server" ScriptMode="Release" />
```

And this in a usercontrol

```
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="updateProgress1" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="CustomerListUpdatePanel" DisplayAfter="0" DynamicLayout="false">
        <ProgressTemplate>
            <asp:Literal ID="loadingLiteral" runat="server" Text="<%$resources:Label,Loading %>" />
        </ProgressTemplate>
    </asp:UpdateProgress>
    <asp:UpdatePanel id="CustomerListUpdatePanel" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="SearchButton" EventName="Click" />
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:repeater id="CustomerListRepeater" runat="server">
```

1. Problem here is that when i press the SearchButton the update panel updates but the UpdateProgress does not show it self, even if it takes a few seconds.. [somewhat solved by Yuriy Rozhovetskiy].
2. Problem is that the child buttons inside the updatepanel do not cause a total postback, instead they only reload the update panel, so it seems ChildrenAsTriggers="false" does not work or im miss understanding it.

Im using AjaxControlToolkit 4.1.50731.0.

Edit: also the UpdateProgress seems to display it self if a button is pressed inside the update panel...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Associating an UpdateProgress with an UpdatePanel Control:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updateprogress.aspx)

> The AssociatedUpdatePanelID property has the following effect on
>   UpdateProgress control behavior:
>
> - When the AssociatedUpdatePanelID property is not set, the
>     UpdateProgress control is displayed for the following postbacks:
>
>   - Postbacks that originate from inside any UpdatePanel control.
>   - Postbacks that originate from controls that are asynchronous
>       triggers    for any UpdatePanel control.
> - When the AssociatedUpdatePanelID property is set to an UpdatePanel 
>     control ID, the UpdateProgress control is displayed for postbacks
>     that originate from inside the associated UpdatePanel control.

Comment: Ok that clears things up, but i don't want postbacks that originate from inside the update panel to update the panel i want them to reload the page...

Comment: You must specify a PostbackTrigger for each control inside an UpdatePanel that must fire synchronous postback: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.postbacktrigger.aspx

Comment: Ok the PostbackTrigger did the opposite compare to what i was expecting and it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about #Problem 1.

Regarding #Problem 2... I think your understanding might not be correct.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.childrenastriggers.aspx

Comment: ChildrenAsTriggers="false" does this only work if i nest update panels or what are you trying to tell me? the text does not define what happens if i only have one updatepanel and set ChildrenAsTriggers="false"...

Comment: Assume that there are two Update Panels... A and B. If there are multiple buttons in both A and B, whenever you press that buttons, the default would be that it would cause an updatePanel PostBack, since ChildrenAsTriggers = "true" by default. Now, if there is a button in A that you want to NOT trigger a postback in A, you would use ChildrenAsTriggers = "false" so that A is not updated, while B would be.

Comment: that might be true but in my case i only have one... but any way PostbackTrigger solved my problem!